# ASP.NET GridView - Adding a summary expandable row under the itemrow

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I want to be able to add a button that uses javascript to expand a summary/info row under the itemrow its self.  It will contain text/notes/etc/buttons/etc...  I want to be able to do this as simply as possible.  I can't seem to find any good resources that help me to do this. It also does not have to be JSON or anything, it could load all of the data at once.

Bill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that trying to get something to pop **under** a row in a GridView is an exercise in futility.  Any time I've wanted to display new data in a row under the parent row, I've used a Repeater.  Much more control over layout than a GridView, though less out-of-the-box functionality.